# If $p$ is a prime and $p$ divides $a^3$ then $p$ divides $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have to either give a proof or provide a counterexample for this question. $a, b$ are non-zero intergers.

If $p$ is a prime and $p|a^3$ then $p|a$

I think this is true but do not know how to go about proving this question.

Comment: unique factorization  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer

Comment: If $p$ is a prime and $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$. You have $p|a^3$, so $p|(a \cdot a \cdot a)$. Can you finish it?

Comment: @nsanger how can I assume that $p|ab$ if I was not given that? Is that something we know it being prime?

Comment: @Abbi If a prime divides a product then it divides some factor of the product (by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, i.e. existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations). Apply that to the prime $p$ dividing the product $\,a\cdot a\cdot a.\ $

Comment: I'm just stating a general theorem: if a prime divides a product of two numbers, then it must divide one of those numbers. So if $p|a^3$, then $p|a \cdot a^2$, and by this theorem $p|a$ or $p|a^2$. In the first case is true, we are done. In the second case, $p|a \cdot a$, so $p|a$ or $p|a$, and we are done again. This completes the proof.

Comment: @nsanger That's  what Modded Bear wrote in his answer. Why repeat it?

Comment: @BillDubuque I was just elaborating on my earlier comment, since Abbi asked a question about it. I didn't even see Modded Bear's post until now ...

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ divides $a^2\times a$ then $p$ divides $a^2$ or $a$ by Euclid's lemma. If it divides $a$ we are done, if it divides $a^2$ we can use euclid's lemma again.